# Why does 13.04 cause my laptop screen to go completely black?

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, laptop, screen, brightness

I have been using Ubuntu for several years, but this is the first time I have had a problem like this.  When I upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04, every time I boot into Ubuntu and the login screen is supposed to show up, my screen remains black.  I can't see any part of the login screen.  Typing on the keyboard and moving the mouse doesn't help at all.  The same happens when I lock my screen and walk away.  When I come back, no keyboard or mouse movement bring the display back up.  The only way I have overcome this is by using my keyboard's "brighten the screen" button.  Only then does the screen the login or lock menu.  I was hoping that at some point, an update would fix the problem.  But as of now, it has stayed the same, and I have been putting up with it for nearly three months.  Why does 13.04 cause my laptop screen to go black?  Is there a way to fix it?

The laptop in question is a HP Pavilion dv4-2160us Entertainment Notebook

Comment: possible duplicate of [Black screen after updating Ubuntu 11.04 and Mobility HD 4250](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64734/black-screen-after-updating-ubuntu-11-04-and-mobility-hd-4250)

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported as a bug.

[Bug #765438 On startup, the backlight is off on laptop](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/765438)

Comment: Thank you for the link :) But I'm a little confused, wojox.  I see that it's listed, but does that mean it hasn't been fixed yet?

Comment: And what should I do about my issue?  Should I report it somewhere?

Comment: It's been reported. Just subscribe to the bug list for now as "affects me".

Comment: Okay :) I see where it says "This bug affects 123 people" and the links "Also effects project" and "Also effects distribution".  So how do I subscribe like you mentioned?